# Cedet - Wrong type argument , stringp, 1

Tags: emacs, cedet

I am using the latest cedet version from bzr.   My cedet configuration is given below ( Taken from Alex Ott's file ).

```
(setq cedet-root-path (file-name-as-directory "~/cedet"))  
(load-file (concat cedet-root-path "cedet-devel-load.el"))  
(add-to-list 'load-path (concat cedet-root-path "contrib"))  

;; select which submodes we want to activate

(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-mru-bookmark-mode)  
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semanticdb-minor-mode)  
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode)  
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode)  
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-cedet-m3-minor-mode)  
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-highlight-func-mode)  
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semanticdb-minor-mode)  

;; Activate semantic

(semantic-mode 1)
```

I always get error "Wrong type argument , stringp 1"  whenever I open a C source code.
 Looks like (semantic-mode 1)
 is causing the issue.  Any help is appreciated.

I am using emacs 24, and I didn't see this issue if I use cedet that comes with emacs.

EDIT : Stack trace attached. Will send this to cedet-delevel mailing list also.   .~/.semanticdb is not created yet( new laptop ).

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp 1)
string-match("\n" 1 0)
split-string(1 "\n")
semantic-cpp-defs(1)
semantic-gcc-setup()
semantic-default-c-setup()
semantic-new-buffer-fcn()
semantic-mode(1)
eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/sudheesh/Dropbox/cedet_new.el" nil t)  ;     Reading at buffer position 898
load-with-code-conversion("/home/sudheesh/Dropbox/cedet_new.el" "/home/sudheesh/Dropbox /cedet_new.el" nil nil)
```

load("/home/sudheesh/Dropbox/cedet_new.el" nil nil t)
   load-file("~/Dropbox/cedet_new.el")

**SOLVED:
This issue is solved now.  I haven't installed g++ compiler.  The issue is because of this. Installing g++ compiler solved this issue.  Thanks to the support of David Engster from cedet-dlevel mailing list.**

Comment: do these lines are first in your `~/.emacs`?

Comment: I tried your configuration except the first three lines and it did not throw the error. Try disabling either of the first three lines and you might be able to isolate the problem.

Comment: error make occur if built-in cedet was loaded before cedet from bzr...

Comment: Yeah.  Infact I have started emacs with -q option and then did M-x load-file. The file contains only these lines.  I am not sure whether built-in cedet is loaded by default.  My .emacs doesn't contains any other lines other than the one pasted above. Is there any way to confirm that?   I have tried what N.N suggested. Still see the same issue.  The issue is seen only when I tried to load a C Source file.

Comment: Enable "Debug on error", obtain stacktrace & post it to cedet-devel mailing list.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977385/emacs-cedet-multiple-projects-and-code-completion on how to get debug information

Comment: One thing to try - delete `~/.semanticdb` directory, this could be a source of problem...

Comment: Added stack trace as part of the question above. Not sure whether it will be useful to you.